# C() function in R returning date column as double instead of date

Tags: r, jira-rest-api

I am trying to fetch data from JIRA using jirAgileR library.
All the date fields are returning values in date format except for duedate.
It returns values like 18466.00, 18473.00 etc.
The only difference between duedate and rest of the date fields is that duedate is date type and rest of the fields are datetime.

```
library(JirAgileR, quietly = T)
library(knitr, quietly = T)
library(dplyr, quietly = T)

if (is.null(JIRABaseURL)) JIRABaseURL
if (is.null(username)) username
if (is.null(password)) password

fields1<-get_jira_issues(domain = JIRABaseURL,
  username = username,
  password = password,
  jql_query = "project in('My Project')",
  fields = c('duedate', 'updateddate', 'components'), 
  maxResults = 50,
  verbose = FALSE,
  as.data.frame = TRUE)
```

how can I fix the duedate in this code?
updateddate is fetching data in correct format.

Comment: Ideally there's a way to fix it upstream, but I bet you can fix it downstream by using `as.Date("1970-01-01") + YOUR_DATES`, so that 18466 becomes 2020-07-23 etc

Comment: or `as.Date(YOUR_DATES, origin="1970-01-01")`, identical results

Comment: Hi Jon/r2evans can you guys please check the updated code let me know how to covert it there?